# Delete duplicate rows for greater then 1

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have a script that looks for duplicates. I want to know how now to delete those duplicates.

```
Select LastName, FirstName, DateOfBirth, Count (*) As Duplicates
From PatientDemographics2
Group by FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth
Having count (*) >1
Order by LastName, FirstName Asc
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and tag it with which DBMS you are using?

Comment: This might help: http://www.codaffection.com/sql-server-article/delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `ROW_NUMBER()` to detect duplicate

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT LastName, FirstName, DateOfBirth
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LastName, FirstName, DateOfBirth ORDER BY LastName) AS rn
    FROM PatientDemographic2
)
DELETE FROM cte 
WHERE rn > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply:

```
DELETE FROM PatientDemographics2 WHERE id NOT IN (
 SELECT MIN(id) i1 FROM PatientDemographics2
 GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth
)
```

demo: https://rextester.com/KOZI16883